# Node.js --cpu-prof flag: Failed to convert CPU profile message to V8 string

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, profiling

I'm using the `--cpu-prof` flag to generate a `cpuprofile` of my Node.js 18.16.0 application. When I try to initiate the creation of the `cpuprofile`, I get this error: `Failed to convert CPU profile message to V8 string`.

I'm hosting my app in a Docker container within Azure App Service. This error hasn't appeared anywhere else on the Internet - What does it mean, and how can I resolve it?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /build

COPY . .

RUN npm ci

RUN npm run compile

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```